# Candy Machine v2 - error: required option '-k, --keypair <path>' not specified

Tags: solana, candy-machine

I have done numerous tutorials, and followed everything step by step but I keep getting stuck at this one step, running the following command:

```
npx ts-node ~/solana-nft/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \ 
-e devnet \
-k keypair.json \ 
-cp config.json \ 
./assets
I have done this in multiple variations but I keep getting the error:
error: required option '-k, --keypair ' not specified
```

Help?! Driving me nuts

Yarn version 1.22.18
Node version v14.17.0
solana-cli 1.9.13
ts-node version v10.7.0

I tried running

```
npx ts-node ~/solana-nft/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \ 
-e devnet \
-k keypair.json \ 
-cp config.json \ 
./assets
```

and I always get the failure "error: required option '-k, --keypair <path> not specified'

I have tried multiple variations according to several tutorials and every time I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This might be just be the way that it was copy-pasted, but the command has one additional space at the end of a few lines, making the escaped newline `\` fail. So instead of:

```
npx ts-node ~/solana-nft/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \ 
-e devnet \
-k keypair.json \ 
-cp config.json \ 
./assets
```

you need to do

```
npx ts-node ~/solana-nft/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \
-e devnet \
-k keypair.json \
-cp config.json \
./assets
```

Answer (score 0):

I think path to keypair is not correct. You create keypair:

```
solana-keygen new --outfile ~/.config/solana/devnet.json
```

then set this as default:

```
 solana config set --keypair ~/.config/solana/devnet.json
```

then you run upload command specifying `~/.config/solana/devnet.json` as -k:

```
ts-node ~/solana-nft/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet -k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json -cp ./config.json ./assets
```

Answer (score 0):

If the key pair path is correct and everything else checks out just change the `~` in code to `.` (I was experiencing this and this fixed my problem...I'm on a mac) so instead your code should be:

```
ts-node ./metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \ 
-e devnet \
-k keypair.json \ (copy and past the location of the key pair path)
-cp config.json \ 
./assets
```